# Show that $\mathbb{E}\left(|X|^q\right) \leq \left[\mathbb{E}\left(|X|^p\right)\right]^{\frac{q}{p}}$

Tags: random-variables, convex-analysis, means, jensen-inequality

> Let $X$ be a random variable and let $p \in (0, \infty)$ such that $\mathbb{E}\left(|X|^p\right) < \infty$. Show that for all $q \in (0, p)$, we have $\mathbb{E}\left(|X|^q\right) \leq \left[\mathbb{E}\left(|X|^p\right)\right]^{\frac{q}{p}}$. You may use the fact that the function $\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto |x|^r$ is convex for all $r \geq 1$.

Hello I think we need to use Jensen's inequality, in my book defined as:

**Jensen's inequality**: Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in the (possibly infinite) interval $(a, b)$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ exists, and let $g:(a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function such that $\mathbb{E}|g(X)|<\infty$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}(g(X)) \geq g(E(X)) .
$$
But I don't know how to do this and how to give the formal proof.

Comment: What function do you need to apply to $\lvert X \rvert^q$ to get $\lvert X \rvert^p$? Is this function convex? Can you apply Jensen's inequality with using this function?

Comment: $g(t)= t^{\beta /\alpha }$? What do you mean with to $|X|^q$ to get $|X|^p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to identify the correct '$X$' and '$g$'. I will switch notation to $\mathbb{E}(g(Y)) \geq g(\mathbb{E}(Y))$ to avoid confusion.

Here, use $Y = |X|^q$, and $g(y) = |y|^{p/q}$. Note that by assumption, $p/q \geq 1$, so $g$ is convex. By Jensen's inequality,
$$g(\mathbb{E}(Y)) \leq \mathbb{E}(g(Y)).$$
Writing out $g$, you get
$$ |\mathbb{E}(Y)|^{p/q} \leq \mathbb{E}(|Y|^{p/q}). $$
Substituting $Y = |X|^q$, you get
$$ |\mathbb{E}(|X|^q)|^{p/q} \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|^p). $$
Since $\mathbb{E}(|X|^q)$ is nonnegative, you can remove the outer absolute value sign and write
$$ [\mathbb{E}(|X|^q)]^{p/q} \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|^p). $$
Finally, take $q/p$ power on both sides to get
$$ \mathbb{E}(|X|^q) \leq [\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)]^{q/p}. $$

Comment: It's super clear, thank you! Am I allowed to choose a random variable $Y$ and a function $g(y)$? Do I need to show  it is a convex function?

Comment: Of course you are allowed. Choosing the appropriate $Y$ and $g(y)$ is the key to the question. As for convexity, the question already says you can use the fact $x \mapsto |x|^r$ is convex for $r \geq 1$. Here, we just use slightly different notation: $g(y) = |y|^{p/q}$. By assumption, $q \in (0, p)$, so in particular, $p/q \geq 1$ holds. So $g(y) = |y|^{p/q}$ is convex.